# wait for one fetch to finish before starting the next

Tags: javascript, ajax, ecmascript-6, fetch-api

I have a list of data that I am sending to google cloud. My current code looks like this:

```
const teams = ['LFC', 'MUFC', 'CFC'];

teams.forEach(team => {
    fetch({
      url: URL,
      method: 'PUT',
      body: team
    });
})
```

This works with one `team` but it is timing out if sending multiple files and the files are bigger. I am sending images over and not strings. To solve this I need to `POST` the data one file by one, and wait for the previous `POST` to complete before sending the subsequent one. Can anyone advise the best way of doing this?

Worth noting that I don't have any control over the number of files that 
are uploaded.

Comment: If you have access to the `npm`, you could install the `bluebird` and use `Promise.reduce`; Promise.reduce will execute an array of promises one by one as they resolved and allow you to "reduce" the previous results into one final result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a `reduce` instead of `forEach`, with `.then()`.

The following will store the promise of the last `fetch` in `acc` (the accumulator parameter of `reduce`), and appends the new `fetch` inside of a `then` listener, to ensure that the previous `fetch` is finished:

```js
const teams = ['LFC', 'MUFC', 'CFC'];

teams.reduce((acc, team) => {
  return acc.then(() => {
    return fetch({
      url: URL,
      method: 'PUT',
      body: team
    });
  })
}, Promise.resolve())
  .then(() => console.log("Everything's finished"))
  .catch(err => console.error("Something failed:", err))
```

```js
//Simulate fetch:
const fetch = team => new Promise(rs => setTimeout(() => {rs();console.log(team)}, 1000))

const teams = ['LFC', 'MUFC', 'CFC'];

teams.reduce((acc, team) => {
  return acc.then(() => {
    return fetch({
      url: URL,
      method: 'PUT',
      body: team
    });
  })
}, Promise.resolve())
  .then(() => console.log("Everything's finished"))
  .catch(err => console.error("Something failed:", err))
```

You can even write a general helper function for it:

```js
const teams = ['LFC', 'MUFC', 'CFC'];

const promiseSeries = (arr, cb) => arr.reduce((acc, elem) => acc.then(() => cb(elem)), Promise.resolve())

promiseSeries(teams, (team) => {
  return fetch({
    url: URL,
    method: 'PUT',
    body: team
  })
})
  .then(() => console.log("Everything's finished"))
  .catch(err => console.error("Something failed:", err))
```

```js
//Simulate fetch:
const fetch = team => new Promise(rs => setTimeout(() => {rs();console.log(team)}, 1000))

const teams = ['LFC', 'MUFC', 'CFC'];

const promiseSeries = (arr, cb) => arr.reduce((acc, elem) => acc.then(() => cb(elem)), Promise.resolve())

promiseSeries(teams, (team) => {
  return fetch({
    url: URL,
    method: 'PUT',
    body: team
  })
})
  .then(() => console.log("Everything's finished"))
  .catch(err => console.error("Something failed:", err))
```

Or, even better, if you can (it's ES2017), use `async/await` (it's more readable):

```js
const teams = ['LFC', 'MUFC', 'CFC'];

async function upload(teams){
  for(const team of teams){
    await fetch({
      url: URL,
      method: 'PUT',
      body: team
    });
  }
}

upload(teams)
  .then(() => console.log("Everything's finished"))
  .catch(err => console.error("Something failed:", err))
```

```js
//Simulate fetch:
const fetch = team => new Promise(rs => setTimeout(() => {rs();console.log(team)}, 1000))

const teams = ['LFC', 'MUFC', 'CFC'];

async function upload(teams) {
  for (const team of teams) {
    await fetch({
      url: URL,
      method: 'PUT',
      body: team
    });
  }
}

upload(teams)
  .then(() => console.log("Everything's finished"))
  .catch(err => console.error("Something failed:", err))
```

Comment: I'd mention that this revolves around Promises, for those who aren't familiar.

Answer (score 8):

You can use async/await with a for...of loop. Each call will "hold" the loop, until it's done, and then the loop will continue the next call:

```
const teams = ['LFC', 'MUFC', 'CFC'];

async function send(teams) {
  for (const team of teams) {
    await fetch({
      url: URL,
      method: 'PUT',
      body: team
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: this is a nice solution, and tidier than the last one, but I have only seen it now and given the green tick! thanks though!

Comment: @Peter you can always change the accepted answer if you think a better answer should be accepted.

Comment: @WaiHaLee I know, but the accepted answer had added the same thing, not sure if it was before or after this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of async/await, as follows:

```
const teams = ['LFC', 'MUFC', 'CFC'];

teams.forEach(async (team) => {
    await fetch({
      url: URL,
      method: 'PUT',
      body: team
    });
})
```

Comment: Does async/await work in a forEach callback? I don't think it works in any of the Array higher-order functions... *EDIT* Just tested, and as I suspected, it doesn't work. If you make a simple Promise-based delay function that wraps setTimeout and an array of times that are not sorted (like 100, 500, 250), a for...of... with await correctly runs them in array order, while forEach runs them in time order, asynchronously.